# Trying to identify the newest and second newest file in a directory

Tags: python

I am trying to identify the newest and second newest files in a directory.  This is the code I intended to use:

```
CONFIGS = "/Users/root/dev/config-files/"
allConfigs = sorted(os.listdir(CONFIGS), key=os.path.getctime)
t1 = "%s/%s" % (CONFIGS, allConfigs[-1])
t2 = "%s/%s" % (CONFIGS, allConfigs[-2])
```

I am encountering this error, which I can't figure out why:

```
MBA:dev root$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 19 2012, 00:55:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> CONFIGS = "/Users/root/dev/config-files/"
>>> allConfigs = sorted(os.listdir(CONFIGS), key=os.path.getctime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 64, in getctime
    return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'newest.txt'
>>>
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns *relative* names, so you'll have to use `os.path.join` to make them absolute:

```
allConfigs = sorted(os.listdir(CONFIGS),
    key=lambda p: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(CONFIGS, p))
```

Comment: I didn't think of this.  (It seems so obvious now).  Thank you, Martijn!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is missing closing bracket:

```
allConfigs = sorted(os.listdir(CONFIGS),
   key=lambda p: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(CONFIGS, p)))
```