# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, ioerror

im having problems trying to run an iteration over many files in a folder, the files exist, if I print file from files I can see their names...
Im quite new to programming, could you please give me a hand? kind regards!

```
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('FDF\FDF'):
    for file in files:
        print file
        fdf = open(file, "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FDF_20110612_140613_...........txt'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9765314/1350424 or 
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: you should add tags with the technologies you use (python in this case) so your question will appear at the relevant places. i added it for you.

Comment: i am not experienced with python, but that backslash seems odd to me `'FDF\FDF'`. paths usually use `/`.

Comment: And of [Having Problems with Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11825923) and [Trying to identify the newest and second newest file in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12715309)

Comment: thanks for oyur inouts, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix each file name with `path` before you open the file.

See the documentation for [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk).

```
import os
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('FDF\FDF'):
    for file in files:
        print file
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        print filepath
        fdf = open(filepath, "r")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('FDF\FDF'):
    for file in files:
        print file
        with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as fdf:
            # code goes here.
```